# How to listen to mouse move-events while mouse button is pressed in Java

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouse, mousemove

I have a problem with mouse events in my program. I'm trying to code a drawing program with a canvas.

The user should draw if he left-clicks and moves the mouse. So I defined a class `Drawer` with a `boolean allow_draw` in it, and I added a method `draw`.

`draw` is called with a `mousemoved` event in the canvas and `allow_draw` is set true and false with `mousepressed` and `released`.

However, `mousemoved` isn't firing while I press the mouse button...

My question is: how can I listen to mouse movements while a mouse button is pressed.

Hope you know what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you please post your source code?  Please try adding a MouseMotionListener.  Here is an example from a project I am working on.

```
addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {

        public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            formMouseDragged(evt);
        }
        public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            formMouseMoved(evt);
        }
    });`
```

Comment: It is not clear to me why you need the 'allow_draw' flag, but a note of caution, please make sure you properly synchronize access to allow_draw.  Otherwise you will have issues with the currency of that variable.

Comment: thank you, now it works! :)
i wrote in the constructor of my main and designer class

`

public CanvasTest() {      
        initComponents();
        
        this.drw = new Drawer(this);
        this.canvas.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener(this));
        this.canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseClickListener(this));
        //this.canvas.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotion(this));
    }
`

Comment: sorry, codehighlighting won't work to me...but i did as you :)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider,

- using a combination of MouseListener and MouseMotionListener, which is conveniently combined in the MouseAdapter class.
- Turn drawing *on* when mousePressed occurs.
- Turn drawing *off* when mouseReleased occurs
- Draw within mouseDragged if drawing is on (use an if block).
- Add your MouseAdapter object twice to the component, with the `addMouseListener(...)` method and the `addMouseMotionListener(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

A mouse move event with a pressed button would be a drag event. Simply listen to 'MouseListener#mouseDragged', it is what you're looking for.